# MATLAB Creating a 2 by 2 matrix from four lists?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to construct a time-dependent matrix `A`

Given

```
%t = [1,2,3];
A11 = [1,2,3]; %This is time-dependence of A(1,1)
A12 = [2,3,4]; %This is time-dependence of A(1,2)
A21 = [1,1,1]; %This is time-dependence of A(2,1)
A22 = [2,2,2]; %This is time-dependence of A(2,2)
```

such that

at `t = 1`,
`A = [1 2;1 2];`

at `t = 2`
`A = [2 3;1 2];`

at `t = 3`
`A = [3 4;1 2];`

In general the four lists are much longer. How can I construct a list of matrix `A` like that so that I know what `A` is at each timestep for eigenvalues calculation.

After I do that, I want to find the eigenvectors at each timestep. For example,

`[V D] = eig(A)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a 3D matrix, try

```
A = cat(3, [1, 2; 1, 2], [2, 3; 1, 2], [3, 4; 1, 2])
```

Or if you need to build it out of your `A11`, `A12`, etc... lists then how about

```
permute(cat(3, [A11;A21], [A12;A22]), [1,3,2])
```

Comment: I dont know `[1, 2; 1, 2], [2, 3; 1, 2], [3, 4; 1, 2]` beforehand. I handwrite it in the example. In general I am given 4 lists which is much longer.

Comment: @kww then stack them as I have shown in my edit and 'rotate' the resulting 3D matrix using `permute`

Comment: thanks. What is `[1,3,2]` doing here? How can I also calculate the eigenspectrum of `A` at each timestep?

Comment: @kww use a loop. Read the docs for `permute` the `[1,3,2]` is telling it the order to rearrange the dimensions to so in this case it leaves dimension 1 (the rows) alone and swaps dimensions 2 and 3